# Magento - How can I add updated_at on core_config_data

Tags: database, api, magento, configuration

I need to add a column in 'core_config_data' with timestamp/updated_at. The sql part would not be a problem, but I'm trying to extend an API so that I can get that timestamp. And that's where I get stuck. I don't know how to get information from that column. Can anybody help?

EDIT:
To explain a bit better...

My core_config_data table now shows something like this:

| config_id |  scope  | scope_id |      path         |   value    |     updated_at      |

So, I need to get the "updated_at". I know how to get the value: Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title')

But how do I get the "updated_at"? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself and I'll post it in case somebody wants to do something with it...

```
$configDataCollection = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')->getCollection();

$conf = array();
$path = 'section/group/field';
foreach ($configDataCollection as $data) {
    if ($data->getPath() == $path) {
        $conf = array(
            'config_id' => $data->getConfigId(),
            'path' => $data->getPath(),
            'value' => $data->getValue(),
            'updated_at' => $data->getUpdatedAt()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: in this solution you iterate over the whole table which for a large table can be very slow and resource consuming. Furthermore you do not take the current scope into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

When you save data in admin panel of your module then you can get that data like

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
```

You need to save first "updated_at" field from your module and after that you can get value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but doesn't really help me. I need to get the updated_at, not the value. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$requestedPath = 'general/locale/code';
$configValue = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('path', $requestedPath)
    ->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'stores')
    ->addFieldToFilter('scope_id', Mage::app()
                      ->getStore()->getStoreId())
                      ->getFirstItem();
```

But you must remember that such solution will not make usage of the fallback for config. So it is not perfect, even far from perfect.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know why, when I add any of ->addAttributeToFilter it breaks. Do you have any idea?

Comment: my bad .. addAttributeToFilter is for EAV models - and core_config_data is not an EAV model - i updated my answer:) now it should be ok :)